# Добавление данных в mysql не в той кодировке

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго всем времени суток

Имеем переменную, при выводе - все нормально, которая нормально отображается при кодировке ascii (и если кодировку не писать вообще). Обычным запросом mysql добавляю переменные в БД - каракозябры (пробовал бд с разными кодировками). Если попробовать отрезать от переменной первый символ - опять каракозябры. Подскажите, в чем может быть дело?

p.s. Может нужно переменной кодировку назначить?

Comment: а `charset` у таблицы(каждого столбца) смотрели?

Comment: хоть кто то откликнулся. cp1251_general_ci. ммм... значение переменной которую добавляю в бд != переменной той, если ее выделить и скопировать. Может в этом дело? может нужно как то сбросить кодировку?

Comment: Я с кодировкой сам долго парился. Мой тебе совет- начни с нуля и все в единой кодировке(и постоянно следи за ней). А кодировку лучше используй UTF-8

Comment: та же история, где все с кодировкой utf-8. вопрос то в другом. если я добавляю в БД каракозябры (которые прожевывает браузер) то получается нужно как то поменять караказябрам кодировку. только вот как. непонятно 8-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Желательно, но не обязательно иметь везде UTF-8.
Но в любом случае необходимо случае:

1. после подключения к БД необходимо указать, в какой кодировке он будет с вами работать.
2. для строковых данных в БД необходимо указывать кодировку
3. для вывода в браузер необходимо отправлять header с указанной кодировкой.

Потом проблемы с кодировкой между приложением, базой данных и выводом можно забыть.

Comment: я несовсем корректно задал вопрос. но на заданный вопрос - спасибо. буду иметь ввиду